# “Removing” reference from its ReferenceQueue

Tags: java, weak-references

Sometimes I need to ensure that some references won't be processed while examination from the associated `ReferenceQueue`. Generally at those moments I don't know reachability status of the referent.

The only way I've came up with:

```
class MyReference<V> extends SoftReference<V> {
    private boolean active = true;

    public MyReference(V referent, ReferenceQueue<? super V> queue) {
        super(referent, queue);
    }

    public void disable() {
        active = false;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
}

// examination
Reference<? extends V> ref;
while ((ref = referenceQueue.poll()) != null) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    MyReference<V> myRef = (MyReference<V>) ref;
    if (myRef.isActive()) {
        // process ref
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: This is the best way I can think of to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a flaw in your logic that is insurmountable......

SoftReferences, once they are added to the queue, have already lost the Referent instance. I cannot think of any reason why you would want to handle an 'active' queued (the value has been GC'd) softreference in any way differently from an 'inactive' one.

Once the reference has been queued it's too late to do anything about the instance it was softly referencing.

On the other hand, if you want to 'process' a referant, and make sure it is not GC'd during the processing, then jsut keep a reference to it:

```
V referent = softref.get();
if (referent == null) {
    // it's already been GC'd (and at some point we will see it poll'd from the Q)
    return;
}
// do things with our referent
// since our referent varaible is a hard-reference,
//      nothing can happen to the soft reference.
....

// then clear our reference (or return from our method,
// or clear our hard reference in some other way)
referent = null;
// after this the referent can (possibly) be GC'd again
```

---

EDIT after comments:

From the [Javadoc for SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html):

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is softly reachable. At that time it may choose to clear atomically all soft references to that object and all soft references to any other softly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong references. At the same time or at some later time it will enqueue those newly-cleared soft references that are registered with reference queues.

The GC will only nequeue **newly cleared** soft references. Further, from the [SoftReference.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html#get%28%29) method, we have:

> Returns this reference object's referent. If this reference object has been cleared, either by the program or by the garbage collector, then this method returns null

Finally, here is a [third-party 'reference' on 'references'](http://www.pawlan.com/monica/articles/refobjs/) ... heh. It appears to be quite good.

---

EDIT 2: how to keep a value 'active' (responding to comments)

If the requirement is to prevent a particular Soft reference referent from being GC'd, the answer is relatively simple: create a hard reference and keep it.... For example:

```
private static final IdentityHashMap<MyType, Object> active = new .....;
private static final Object token = new Object();

private static final boolean forceActive(SoftReference<MyType> reference) {
    MyType referent = softref.get();
    if (referent == null) {
        // it's already been GC'd ... and ...
        // if the reference was created with a ReferenceQueue, we can
        // expect to 'poll' the reference from that queue at some point
        // maybe we have already done that....
        return false;
    }
    // referent is now a hard reference, we are guaranteed that `reference`
    // is not on any Queue, and that it will not be GC'd (since we have a hard reference)

    // we want to keep our referent 'active', so we need to keep a hard reference:
    // the key in the identity hash map is our hard link.
    active.put(referent, token);
    // we exit our keep-active method, but the hard reference remains.
    return true;
}

private static final boolean deActive(SoftReference<MyType> reference) {
    MyType referent = softref.get();
    if (referent == null) {
        // it's already been GC'd ... and ... that means it was not
        // in our active map (otherwise it would not have been GC'd).
        return false;
    }
    // if the map contains the referent as a key, then it will return 'token'.
    // and we have now successfully removed the hard-reference to the referent.
    return token == active.remove(referent);
}
```

Comment: "*Some time after the garbage collector determines that the reachability of the referent has changed* to the value corresponding to the type of the reference, it will add the reference to the associated queue. At this point, the reference is considered to be enqueued." -- I haven't found in the docs clear statement that `ref.get() == null` for references in the queue.

Comment: @leventov updated reference material

Comment: I have a slightly different issue. In your example code, I want to prevent the ref from being enqueued after `referent == null` check. At that point I don't know, is the ref is already enqueued or not (in the latter case I can simple write `softref = null;` to "remove" the soft ref from the queue).

Comment: More complicated answer than this space has.... let me edit again....

Comment: Editing done. All the best.

Comment: No. Suppose referent is GC'd (`ref.get() == null`, but I don't know is the ref is already enqueued or not. If it isn't enqueued, I just need to "forget" the ref. Otherwise, I need to "remove" it from the queue (that was the purpose of `MyReference` class from the question).

Comment: My recommendation is that you don't bother with the queue. it ads no value to you. You already have SoftReference instances that you are keeping 'outside' of the GC system, and you don't need to keep track of when the referent is GC'd. You just need to make sure that, for certain periods, it is Not GC'd (if it has not been GC'd already)

Comment: @leventov Also, note, that if the referent *is* GC'd, the Reference *will* be have `get() == null` and also be enqueued 'at some point'... but you don't know where in the queue it will be, and there is only 1 method you can use on the queue, and that's `poll()` and that may not remove *your* Reference.

Comment: in your case you can easily do what you want to do, without using the Queue at all.

Comment: No. I touch some refs and don't want to process them through the `queue.poll()`, but there are some other refs which follow the "normal" queue way.

Comment: Once you register a SoftReference with a queue there is no way to deregister it, other than to clear it's referent value.

Comment: @leventov, Re "*haven't found in the docs*", admittedly the wording of the docs isn't clear. But fwiw: http://archive.is/j4Hsg#selection-283.281-283.294 and http://archive.is/SP2B8#selection-275.378-275.391

Comment: @leventov, See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

<`while (... referenceQueue.poll()`> is a busy loop. 98.5% of times, you will not want it. Opt for [`.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html#remove()) instead.

Otherwise, it looks pretty good. If you need an additional functionality which is to asap `ReleaseResources()`, do this:

```
class MyReference<V> extends SoftReference<V> {
    public V GetObjAndReleaseIfNeeded() {
        V obj = get();
        if(obj === null) ReleaseResources();
    }
    public void ReleaseResources(){
        if(is_released)return;
        // release
        is_released = true;
    }
```

..and in the queue:

```
while (ref = referenceQueue.remove()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    MyReference<V> myRef = (MyReference<V>) ref;
    myRef.ReleaseResources()
}
```

This will ensure that even if the GC takes forever to queue your ref, you'll still `ReleaseResources()` when the user calls `GetObjAndReleaseIfNeeded()`.

Naturally, if the user does not call `GetObjAndReleaseIfNeeded`, your resources will be unreleased even while obj has been out of scope, all the way until the GC queues your ref and the queue has been polled, **if ever**.

A running GC is [never guaranteed](http://archive.is/j4Hsg#selection-283.18-283.21) to ever queue a softreference.

In fact, a GC is never guaranteed to run, ever, thus even weakreferences  are [never guaranteed to be queued](http://archive.is/Y1suz#selection-275.2-275.14) .

**Note: Be careful of synchronization if getting ref and polling queue ain't on the same thread.**